# Fill choices from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Test]";

cnn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

adp.Fill(ds);

Choices sList = new Choices();
```

I want to fill `sList` from table in my database.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get the table you need from the [`Tables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
var dataTable = ds.Tables["Test"];
```

2) Create a method that will convert each `DataRow` to an instance of class you need in your `Choices` list (I call it `Choice` in this example):

```
Choice DataRowToChoice(DataRow row)
{
    return new Choice() { Property1 = row["column1"] as string }; // ... etc.
}
```

You can learn how to retrieve data from a `DataRow` in its documentation: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

3) Iterate through rows:

```
foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    sList.Add(DataRowToChoice(row));
}
```

Documentation of the `Rows` property can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
  Choices sList = new Choices();
  foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Table[0].Rows) {
    sList.Name = dr["name"]; // Or whatever your property is
  }
```